# Limit proof for $1/x$ (as $x \to 1$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-writing

Prove

$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x} = 1$ Using $\epsilon-\delta$

$|\frac{1}{x} - 1| < \epsilon$ for some $|x - 1| < \delta$

$|\frac{1}{x} - 1| = \frac{|1-x|}{|x|}$

Lets require $|x - 1| < b$ for some constant $b$.  Therefore,

$|x| - 1 < |x - 1| < b$

$|x| < b + 1$

So we have,

$|x - 1| < b$

$|x| < b + 1$

---

$\frac{|x-1|}{|x|} < \frac{b}{b+1}$

We require $\frac{b}{b+1} = \epsilon$ so therefore,

$b = \epsilon(b+1)$

$b(1 - \epsilon) = \epsilon$

$b = \frac{\epsilon}{1 - \epsilon}$

So, for $\delta = b = \frac{\epsilon}{1 - \epsilon}$ the inequality holds true. $\blacksquare$

Is this correct? because on another thread it says $\delta = \epsilon/2$

Thanks!

Comment: It is false that $$\begin{cases}|x-1|<b\\|x|<b+1\end{cases}\implies \frac{|x-1|}{|x|}<\frac b{b+1}$$ For example $$\begin{cases}2<3\\3<5\end{cases}\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\implies \frac23<\frac35$$

Comment: @Timbuc, why so?

Comment: Look at the counterexample, @Amad

Comment: @Timbuc, thanks, I see. Okay, so I have no clue what to do!

Comment: @Timbuc You can't have $b=3,$ $b+1=5$ in your counterexample. Instead, let's try this: $b=1,$ $x=\frac 13,$ so $\frac{|x-1|}{|x|}=2>\frac 12=\frac{b}{b+1}.$

Comment: @DavidK, it was just an example to illustrate the point.

Comment: @Amad27 In limit proofs, it's often a mistake to try to "solve" for $\delta$ in some equation so that $\delta$ is a simple function of $\epsilon.$ It doesn't work here. Even if you didn't make the $\frac b{b+1}$ mistake, you would run into trouble later. The choice $\delta=\epsilon/2$ is a "safe" value, not an exact solution.

Comment: @Timbuc The example had $\frac{b}{b+2}$ on the right-hand side of the inequality. OP's claim had $\frac{b}{b+1}$. OP's claim in fact is true when $x=3.$ Counterexamples occur at other values of $x.$

Comment: Again @DavidK : I attacked the point that $\;a<b\,,\,c<d\implies\frac ac<\frac bd\;$ . The *very particular* case the OP wrote, **even** if it were true, would require a proof...but it also isn't true in that case.

Comment: @Timbuc Granted, OP appears to be assuming that we can write $\frac ac < \frac bd$ whenever $a<b$ and $c<d.$ If you had specified that _that_ was the fact you were disproving, not the specific case where $d=c+1,$ that would have been fine. It _seemed_ that you were disputing the result, not the way OP got there, although if I were more perceptive I might have realized what you were actually doing.

Comment: Right @DavidK, that can be confusing. Anyway, with all these comments, I hope this is already clear to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks.  If $ a < b$ and $c < d$ then $a/c < b/d$ is true isnt it? If none of the constants are equal to each other.

Comment: @Amad27, you did the right thing when you opened a separate question about this, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993801/is-this-an-inequality-law-with-division/993810#993820 -- answers are there.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;\epsilon>0\;$ arbitrary . We need to find $\;\delta>0\;$ such that

$$|x-1|<\delta\implies\left|\frac1x-1\right|<\epsilon$$

Now, as you did:

$$\left|\frac1x-1\right|=\frac{|x-1|}{|x|}=\frac{|x-1|}x\le\frac\delta x\stackrel{\text{we want}}\le\epsilon\iff x\ge\frac\delta\epsilon$$

So if we take $\;\delta:=\frac\epsilon2\;$ , we surely have

$$x\ge\frac{\frac\epsilon2}\epsilon=\frac12\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;x\to 1$$