# Is this an inequality law? with division

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

$a < b$

$c < d$ such that $a \ne b \ne c \ne d$

Will it be true that,

$\frac{a}{c} < \frac{b}{d}$

For all positive $a, b, c, d$

Thanks!

Comment: @Adriandmen I wasnt asking for a proof, I just wanted to know if this is true or not.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller denominators tend to lead to larger fractions.  It should be relatively easy to find a counterexample with $a,b$ and $c$ being small and $d$ being very large.  However, if $a<b$  and $c<d$, we can divide that second inequality by $cd$ to get

$$\frac1d<\frac1c$$
$$\frac bd<\frac bc$$
$$\frac ad<\frac bd<\frac bc$$

assuming again that all numbers are positive.

Answer (score 0):

To find a counterexample, simply choose three pairwise distinct numbers $a, b, c$ 
with $0 < a < b$ and $0 < c,$ then solve for $d$ in
$$\frac ac = \frac bd.$$

Is $c < d$? Is $d$ distinct from both $a$ and $b$? If the answers to these questions
are "yes", you have your counterexample. If not, choose a larger value of $d$ that *does*
make all the answers "yes," and verify that
$$\frac ac > \frac bd.$$

The reason this works is that the conditions put no upper bound on $d$, only a lower bound.
So no matter how small we need $\frac bd$ to be in order to construct a counterexample,
there is a $d$ that will make it so. We just need to choose $d$ large enough.

**Edit**: What numbers are *not* counterexamples? Assume that $a, b, c, d$ are all positive, and solve for $d$ in
$$\frac ac < \frac bd.$$
The result will be an inequality with $d$ standing alone on the left side of a $<$ sign
(or the right side of a $>$ sign). 
For any positive $a, b, c$ with $a < b,$ you now know precisely the conditions on $d$
that will satisfy both $c < d$ and $\frac ac < \frac bd.$
It is also easy to see the range of values of $d$ that will satisfy $c < d$
but *not* satisfy $\frac ac < \frac bd.$
(You want to exclude $a$ and $b$ from the range of possible values of $d$, but that
still leaves plenty of examples and counterexamples.)